# Why am i getting this error? Return tag error (page does not link back)

Tags: canonical-link, hreflang

I have a website https://www.safetoconvert.com with multi-language support, so, I have used hreflang tag, but I am doing something wrong.

it's working with all languages except the English language.

- http://hreflang.ninja/check/?url=https://www.safetoconvert.com OK
- http://hreflang.ninja/check/?url=https://www.safetoconvert.com/en Failed
- http://hreflang.ninja/check/?url=https://www.safetoconvert.com/es OK

Please tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a little mistake, you should add language code (en) for the English language.

From:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.safetoconvert.com/" hreflang="en">
```

To:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.safetoconvert.com/en" hreflang="en">
```

Comment: Hey, now I'm getting the same error on the home page.

Comment: Your URL not matching with canonical URL, a canonical link should be the same as your current URL

Comment: I would suggest you, Just redirect url safetoconvert.com/en to safetoconvert.com

Comment: Thank you, I did the same, now my problem fixed.